# Cannot implicitly convert type `bool' to `UnityEngine.RaycastHit'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I tried to cast a line from next to `gameObject` to `gameObject`:

```
bool Valid(Vector3 direction)
{
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    RaycastHit hit = Physics.Linecast (position + direction, direction);
    return (hit.collider == GetComponent<Collider>());
}
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `bool' to`UnityEngine.RaycastHit'

Answer (score 4):

`Physics.Linecast` returns true if there is any collider intersecting the line between `start` and `end`, it does not return a `RaycastHit`.

You have to add the `hit` variable as the third parameter:

```
RaycastHit hit;
Physics.Linecast(position + direction, direction, out hit);
```

See the [API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Linecast.html) for more info.